# how to get link from notification and open in mainactivity webview by firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, webview, push-notification

**What i am Doing:** by these codes i am receiving notification from Firebase and onclick notification opening mainactivity webview default url.

**what i want to do:** i want to open url in mainactivity webview that i will send by Firebase.

i don't know how to implement this(receive url from Firebase notification and open in mainactivity webview )

**notification.java**

```
public class FirebaseMessageReciver extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            //handle when receive notification via data event
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
                showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("message"),remoteMessage.getData().get("link"));
            }
            //handle when receive notification
            if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
                showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }
        }

        private RemoteViews getCustomDesign(String title,String message) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,title);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.message,message);
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
            return remoteViews;

        }

        public void showNotification(String title,String message,String link){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            String channel_id = "web_app_channel";
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channel_id)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setSound(uri)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
                builder=builder.setContent(getCustomDesign(title, message));
            }
            else{
                builder= builder.setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
            }

            NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channel_id,"web_app",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                notificationChannel.setSound(uri, null);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }

            notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());

        }
    }
```

**mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String webAdress = "https://google.com";
    WebView webView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("Token", ""+ FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("allDevices");
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //enable javascript
        webView.loadUrl(webAdress);
}

    private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use intent.putExtra

add this in your code like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
String channel_id = "web_app_channel";
intent.putExtra("link", link);  // add this line for send url
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and add getIntent in MainActivity

```
Log.d("Token", ""+ FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("allDevices");

String urlFromFirebase = getIntent().getStringExtra("link"); //get link from firebase

// for exception
if (urlFromFirebase.equals("")) {
   urlFromFirebase = "https://google.com";
}

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //enable javascript
webView.loadUrl(urlFromFirebase ); //load
```

then you can load url from firebase.

[edit]
I founded

```
showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("message"),remoteMessage.getData().get("link"));
```

this code before you edit, so if you want to edit. try this code.

```
@Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            //handle when receive notification via data event
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
                showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
            }
            //handle when receive notification
            if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
                showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
            }
        }


    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        try {
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(messageBody);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        String channel_id = "web_app_channel";

       // you can edit this part as you want or follow data.
        String title = jsonBody.getString("title");
        String message = jsonBody.getString("message");
        String link = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data").getString("link");

        intent.putExtra("link", link);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setSound(uri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            builder=builder.setContent(getCustomDesign(title, message));
        }
        else{
            builder= builder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channel_id,"web_app",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setSound(uri, null);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

            notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

in my case, i make JSONObject, and get link form data. try this.

Comment: code working good but there is one problem  how to get link by getnotification function i am getting only by getdata

Comment: because i am getting error (error: method showNotification in class FirebaseMessageReciver cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String,String
found: String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)